# Automating Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, cortana-intelligence, azure-machine-learning-service

Is there a way of automating the calls to the Azure Machine Learning Service (AML)?

I’ve created the web service from AML. Now I have to do the calls the automated way. I’m trying to build a system, that connects to a Raspberry Pi for sensor data and gets a prediction from the ML service to be saved with the data itself.

Is there something in Azure to automate this or should I do it within the application?

Comment: In Azure Machine Learning, have you pressed the "Create Web API" button? If so, you now have a REST call you can do from your RPI, I'm not quite sure if that's the question though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you've created the webservice from the experiment and asking about the consumption of the webservice. You can consume the webservice from anything that can do an API call to the endpoint. I don't know the exact architecture of your solution but take a look at this as it might suit your scenario.

Stream analytics on Azure has a new feature called Functions(just a heads-up, its still in preview) that can automate the usage of deployed ML services from your account.Since you are trying to gather info from IoT devices, you might use [Event Hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-csharp-ephcs-getstarted/) or [IoT Hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted/) to get the data and process it using Stream Analytics and during the process you can use the Webservice as Function in SA to achieve on-the-go ML results.

Usage is relatively simple if you are familiar with Stream Analytics or SQL queries in general.This [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-machine-learning-integration-tutorial/) shows the step by step implementation and the usage is below;

```
    WITH subquery AS (  
    SELECT text, "webservicealias"(text) as result from input  
    )  

    Select text, result.[Score]  
    Into output  
    From subquery
```

Hope this helps!

Mert

Answer (score 0):

you can also automatically schedule this using powershell command and any task scheduler

Powershell for Azure ML - https://github.com/hning86/azuremlps  and its usage is described here - https://github.com/hning86/azuremlps#invoke-amlwebservicerrsendpoint

Task Scheduler for powershell - http://www.metalogix.com/help/Content%20Matrix%20Console/SharePoint%20Edition/002_HowTo/004_SharePointActions/012_SchedulingPowerShell.htm